# Show DIV in tooltip for Anchor Tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am very new to Jquery. Everything what I see looks strange.. I need to show a DIV section as a tooltip for Anchor Tag. I could able to toggle the visibility of DIV . But, it is not showing up as a tooltip, rather it is displayed on the top corner of the screen.. Is it possible to show the DIV section just like a Tooltip for the Anchor Tag..

Thanks in advance..

```
<div id = "contact" class = "tooltip" style="display: none">
<asp:Label Font-Bold = "true" ID = "custLbl" runat = "server" Text = "Phone: " ></asp:Label>
<asp:Label Font-Bold = "true" ID = "custMobLbl" runat = "server" Text = "" ></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Label Font-Bold = "true" ID = "custLbl2" runat = "server" Text = "Mail:  " ></asp:Label>
<asp:Label Font-Bold = "true" ID = "custMailLbl" runat = "server" Text = "" ></asp:Label>
</div>

    $(function () {
        $('.contactLink').hover(function () {
            $('#contact').show();
        }, function () {
            $('#contact').hide();
        });
    });



<a  class = "contactLink" href="javascript:void();"> Click me </a>
```

Comment: A div is a screen element, wherever you show, it will alter your page. You might want to look at changing the z-index for the div, and then positioning it next to your anchor tag and then do a show/hide.

Comment: wrap you js into a script tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this onto page

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
   mouseX = e.pageX; 
   mouseY = e.pageY;
});
```

and then change your code as

```
$(function () {
        $('.contactLink').hover(function () {
            $('#contact').show();
            $('#DivToShow').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).show();
        }, function () {
            $('#contact').hide();
        });
    });
```